# Background image with background-size looks bad on IE and Edge

Tags: html, css

It looks perfect in chrome and firefox, but the scaling in IE and Edge is terrible. The size is good but the image looks sharper, the actual image is 2 times bigger than the background size. Is there a way to fix it, I've tried several things I found on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

Comment: could you please post your code or fiddle.

Comment: What value on background-size are you using?

Comment: background: url(image.png);
background-size: cover;

The image is a square and the container is a square, just the container is smaller compared to the image and it looks bad on IE and Edge.

Comment: open this in chrome and edge and you'll see the difference
https://jsfiddle.net/0yq9qpcy/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your relying on the browser to resize your images. Browsers have notoriously poor rendering when scaling images. You should use a specific size and pre-format them in a graphic package beforehand.

I would also consider using an SVG for what you are trying to achieve (I assume the scaled down image is so that on different resolutions, things still look good?) I would seriously consider the flexibility it would give you.

Comment: I assumed since Chrome and Firefox can do it well, there should be a way for other browers too, I guess I was wrong. Thanks for clearing thing up.